# CCleaner does not clean for... itself?

Tags: windows-xp, ccleaner

As on screenshot below. I don't even have BitTorrent application installed anymore. How to remove this entry from CCleaner?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: I added the image to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It likely found some history or files left behind after you uninstalled the BitTorrent. You can check the box and it will clean it.

Comment: If I check both and "Run Cleaner" it only cleans uTorrent and shows count of historical files that was removed. Nothing about BitTorrent. The box with "BitTorrent" also does not dissappear.